# Correct location to save a temporary file in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows

I have a file I need to write to a temp location, what is the best place in Windows? This file needs to not move as I need to read it a couple of times and dispose it when I close the program.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

use

```
Path.GetTempPath();
```

or

```
Path.GetTempFileName();
```

As commentator pointed out, GetTempFileName() is not threadsafe - but you can construct unique file names based on GUIDs.

Comment: Note that GetTenpFileName might need to be called multiple time due to inherent race condition (something else might create the same file between return from GetTempFileName and opening the file).

Comment: @Richard Do you mean another app/process or another thread in the context  **your** app?

Comment: @tanascius https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx states `Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.` So I think `Path.GetTemptFileName()` *is* thread safe.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan: Both. File systems are a global resource, any thread on the system could be trying to get a temporary file. (If your creating files on a share, you could be contending with threads on other computers as well; but having a shared temporary folder seems like a recipe for poor performance.)

Answer (score 11):

The others beat me to it regarding

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()
```

But you can also look into application data folder. That will allow you more control over your file, like the ability have 1 shared for all users or 1 per user.

```
Application.CommonAppDataPath
Application.UserAppDataPath
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the Windows API function `GetTempPath()` from `System.IO.Path` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx))

```
using System.IO

...

myTempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
```

You should be aware that the filesystem might well change during your program's execution. Either the Temp path may change (unlikely, granted), or your temporary file might have been moved or deleted by the user.

Be prepared to check for its existence each time you access it and handle the case when it's not found gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you need your application to write to a temporary location and work in partial trust, you'd need to look into [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts8hk0.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build your own custom temporary filename in reference to a temporary location, I use something like this, to strip off the PATH and apply my own filename ...

```
string wsPDFfile = Path.GetTempPath() + wsStudentID + "_" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetTempFileName()) + ".pdf";
```