# Windows temp file location

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correct location to save a temporary file in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752455/correct-location-to-save-a-temporary-file-in-windows)

Where is a safe place to create tmp file on windows?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe" please? There is already a well known and understood temp folder as the answers show

Comment: i mean on *nix systems i can create a file in /tmp without permission problems i was looking for an equalent location for windows.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364992(VS.85).aspx) API, or the equivalent in your programming environment (for .NET, that would be [Path.GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx)).

Answer (score 4):

In Win32, you use [GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364991(VS.85).aspx), and in .NET, you use [`System.Io.Path.GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(VS.80).aspx).

Not in one of those languages? Check [Creating a Secure Temporary File on Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Creating_a_Secure_Temporary_File).

Answer (score 3):

What about the Temp directory? You can find its location in the `%TEMP%` environment variable or programmatically using the [`GetTempPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364992(VS.85).aspx) function.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using a full-blown programming language, you should place temp files in the folder whose name is stored in the environment variable %TEMP% or %TMP%

Comment: Yes, based on the non-programming nature of the question (no references to a programming language), I would guess this is the answer. If so, this question really belongs on http://superuser.com !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%TMP%` as a valid path that actually points to the users temp folder in windows.

Example (copy `thefile.txt` to the temp folder and rename to `tmpfile.txt`):

```
copy thefile.txt %TMP%\tmpfile.txt
```

To see where the actual location of the temp folder is, just run

```
echo %TMP%
```